# Nginx TCP PROXY forward Client IP

Tags: nginx

I use nginx as tcp reverse proxy. Clients only show me the proxy IP in the backend. But I need real user IP. I try to include proxy_params but it doesn't work.

nginx conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}
stream{
    include /etc/nginx/tcp-proxies/*.proxy;
}
```

xxx.proxy:

```
server{
listen 11111;
proxy_pass xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33333;
}
```

What do I do to include proxy_params for showing real client IP in backend?

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/ This is the only way I've heard of to do it, and your upstream server must also support it.

Comment: I not find this docs and copy from my nginx config, Can I delete my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass real IP as this:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
```

But you need also say your backend to retrive it

For example if you use nginx as backend you need specify  in backend configuration this:

```
set_real_ip_from x.x.x.x/x;
```

Comment: backend dont use nginx or apache.

Answer (score 0):

my backend dont use nginx or apache.

when i set in nginx.conf

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
```

i got this error:

2018/12/09 15:46:54 [emerg] 12162#12162: "proxy_set_header" directive is not            allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:14

Comment: You need to put this directives inside your `server` block. Note that they would work only if your backend can make use of `X-Real-IP` HTTP header. You will see real IPs only if you can set up your backend to show or log value of this header.

Comment: can you show me @Ivan Shatsky with my code snipet? can i use backend nginx with minimal configuration only for show header ip?