# The server receiving the HTTP request identifies the IP address of the container instead of the server's IP address

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, docker-networking

There is a Nginx container that belongs to the `messaging` microservice written **in Laravel** with IP `172.19.0.8` in a server. The container inside the server posts an HTTP request to another server. However, the destination server identifies the IP address of the requester as `172.19.0.8`  not the IP address of the server.

I already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537954/how-to-make-docker-container-see-real-user-ip) and the question is different. The cause of the problem given the link was setting the firewall, while there is no firewall in my server (still a test server and configured yet). I also make an HTTP request to another server and I have no access to that.

This is the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

networks:
  common_network:
    external: true
  messaging_network:
    name: messaging_network
    driver: bridge

services:
  messaging_php:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php8.1.Dockerfile
      args:
        uid: "${UID-1000}"
        gid: "${GID-1000}"
    container_name: "messaging_php"
    image: messaging_php
    restart: always
    tty: true
    networks:
      - messaging_network
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "${MESSAGING_PHP_PORT}:9000"
  messaging_nginx:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    container_name: messaging_nginx
    image: messaging_nginx
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${MESSAGING_NGINX_PORT}:80"
    networks:
      - messaging_network
      - common_network
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - messaging_php
  messaging_mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.26
    container_name: messaging_mysql
    restart: always
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "${MESSAGING_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
        SERVICE_TAGS: "messaging"
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
    networks:
      - messaging_network

volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

This is `nginx.Docerfile`

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

and `default.conf`

```
server {
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    client_max_body_size 64M;

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }



    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass messaging_php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;

    }
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/services/reverse_proxy.conf;
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and `nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout           50000;
    proxy_connect_timeout       60000;
    proxy_send_timeout          60000;
    send_timeout                60000;
    client_max_body_size        50000;
    client_header_timeout       60000;
    client_body_timeout         60000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout        30000;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

How can I fix the problem so that it finds the IP of the server, not the container?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx TCP PROXY forward Client IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/943525/nginx-tcp-proxy-forward-client-ip)

Answer (score 1):

11:34 AM

add

proxy_set_header        Host               $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host   $host:443;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port   443;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto  https;

Comment: I tried that but didn't work